# I have 12 pd dataframes , i want to extract one column from each and pass as new df and rename based on source df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

**I need to extract  "adj close" from all into a new DF and rename based on source and map based on Date

new_DF = date AAL AAPL ALK .....(containing adj close)
please help**

AAL = pd.read_csv("AAL.csv")

AAPL = pd.read_csv("AAPL.csv")

ALK = pd.read_csv("ALK.csv")

AMZN = pd.read_csv("AMZN.csv")

BHC = pd.read_csv("BHC.csv")

CS = pd.read_csv("CS.csv")

DB = pd.read_csv("DB.csv")

GS = pd.read_csv("GS.csv")

GOOG = pd.read_csv("GOOG.csv")

HA = pd.read_csv("HA.csv")

JNJ = pd.read_csv("JNJ.csv")

MRK = pd.read_csv("MRK.csv")

SP500 = pd.read_csv("S&P500.csv")

df = date | Open| high | low |close | adj close |volume

Comment: https://pythonprogramming.net/combining-stock-prices-into-one-dataframe-python-programming-for-finance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. Not having your .csv files means we need to be creative in terms of how to get the data, but imagine you have a `dict` of `DataFrames`, one per ticker.

Here we use [Yahoo finance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) to get similar data. The column we are looking for (`'adj close'`) is not in that data, so for this example we'll use `Close` instead.

```py
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAL', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GOOG']
sources = {ticker: yf.Ticker(ticker).history(period='5d') for ticker in tickers}
```

At this point, we've got data for each ticker. For example:

```py
>>> sources['AAPL']
            Open        High        Low         Close       Volume     Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                                                                          
2022-03-30  178.550003  179.610001  176.699997  177.770004   92633200  0          0           
2022-03-31  177.839996  178.029999  174.399994  174.610001  103049300  0          0           
2022-04-01  174.029999  174.880005  171.940002  174.309998   78699800  0          0           
2022-04-04  174.570007  178.490005  174.440002  178.440002   76468400  0          0           
2022-04-05  177.500000  178.300003  174.419998  175.059998   73311300  0          0
```

In your case, you'd get the data from CSV files, so instead:

```py
sources = {k: pd.read_csv(f'{k}.csv').set_index('Date') for k in tickers}
```

Now, the answer to your question:

```py
df = pd.concat([v['Close'].to_frame(k) for k, v in sources.items()], axis=1)

>>> df
                  AAL        AAPL         AMZN         GOOG
Date                                                       
2022-03-30  18.049999  177.770004  3326.020020  2852.889893
2022-03-31  18.250000  174.610001  3259.949951  2792.989990
2022-04-01  18.240000  174.309998  3271.199951  2814.000000
2022-04-04  18.230000  178.440002  3366.929932  2872.850098
2022-04-05  17.840000  175.059998  3281.100098  2821.260010
```

Again, in your case you would select the `'adj close'` column instead.

Comment: thanks you so much this works but im  not getting the date column like you did , i tried adding date  but im getting an error " 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame"                   df3 = pd.concat([v[['Adj Close','Date']].to_frame(k) for k, v in sources.items()], axis=1)

Comment: Please post some sample data so we can see what it looks like. And please post expected output. Otherwise we'll go in circles. In other words, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: The way to bring date as an index would be `v.set_index('Date').to_frame('Adj Close')`. But my advice would be to set Date as index at load time (`pd.read_csv(...).set_index('Date')`).

Comment: https://jovian.ai/annishamendoza/stock-analysis-and-portfolio-management-capstone-project-ann

Comment: above is my jovian , if can assist me in sorting this out id be deeply indebted

Comment: Yes: replace `sources = {k: pd.read_csv(f'{k}.csv') for k in stocks}` by `sources = {k: pd.read_csv(f'{k}.csv').set_index('Date') for k in stocks}`. I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# load csv data
# define relative path to folder containing csv data
files_folder = '/path/to/csv/'

# load all csv files in one dataframe
df_list = []
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(files_folder, '*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # write here column you want to select
    df_column = df['column_name'].rename(columns={'column_name':file[:-4]})
    df_list.append(df_column)
# concatenate the list of dataframes into one
df_final = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
```

Comment: *rename() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns' *                      i am getting this error on run , any fixes ?